# how to escape '$' in an awk statement in shell alias

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, bash-alias

I'm trying to write an alias that will kill all running php processes.. this is the command i got in my `~/.bash_profile`

```
alias killphp="ps aux | g [p]hp | awk '{print $3}' | xargs kill -9"
```

this command works just fine if i type it as is without the alias.. but if i simply run `killphp` I get this weirdness:

```
grep: warning: recursive search of stdin
kill: illegal process id: (standard
kill: illegal process id: input):2:abdullah
kill: illegal process id: 10.9
kill: illegal process id: 0.2
kill: 2496576: No such process
kill: 20460: No such process
kill: illegal process id: ??
kill: illegal process id: S
kill: illegal process id: 7:14AM
kill: illegal process id: 0:00.28
kill: illegal process id: /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.28/bin/php
kill: illegal process id: /Users/abdullah/dev/php/smartTaxi/app/console
kill: illegal process id: bcc:resque:worker-start
kill: illegal process id: -f
kill: illegal process id: request_queue
kill: illegal process id: --env=dev
kill: illegal process id: (standard
kill: illegal process id: input):3:abdullah
kill: illegal process id: 6.0
kill: illegal process id: 0.1
kill: 2486972: No such process
kill: 9708: No such process
kill: illegal process id: ??
kill: illegal process id: S
kill: illegal process id: 7:14AM
kill: illegal process id: 0:00.08
kill: illegal process id: php
kill: illegal process id: /Users/abdullah/dev/php/smartTaxi/app/../vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/resque.php
```

if I run `type killphp` I get this:

```
killphp is aliased to `ps aux | g [p]hp | awk '{print }' | xargs kill -9'
```

so apparently the `$3` argument to awk is gone! how do I escape it? I tried doing `/$3` and `$$3` but none of them works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd be much better off using `pkill`. But to address your question, make `killphp` a bash function instead of an alias, by putting this into your profile.

```
killphp() {
  ps aux | g [p]hp | awk '{print $3}' | xargs kill -9
}
```

You can then use it just like the alias:

```
killphp
```

You could have escaped the `$` by writing `\$`, but with functions you don't have to worry about quoting.

Comment: questions: 1) why is `pkill` better than just `kill`? 2) how do i run a shell function from command line?

Comment: ah i see how pkill is better.. it saves me all the hassle of awking and grepping.. nice

Comment: @abbood: because you call pkill with the (p)attern: `pkill php`. No messing around with `ps`+`grep` etc. Answered the other question in the answer.

Comment: @abbood: The pattern is a regex, but partial matches are fine so `pkill supervisor` should work. It works for me, anyway.

Comment: you are right.. i was looking at the wrong thing lol :)